# How to integrate Julia with IDE/interpreter/compiler?

Tags: raspbian, ide, julia

I'm having a Raspberry pi4 4GB model, with the raspbian (TWISTER OS) installed. I have installed julia using the `sudo apt install julia` command. But I am having problem with integrating with shell. Previously I tried to install 'Eclipse' but it didn't start. I need some help finding out the right compiler for julia and how to install it. While installing I came to know about a package by the install called `sudo apt install libzmq3-dev` the command didn't work and the package didn't install. I followed this website **https://juliaberry.github.io/**. I'm just a beginner at programming and am interested to learn the programming language. I'm just looking for a way to integrate it with any IDE if available or just move to an easy IDE. Thanks.

Comment: If you are a beginner why are you using anything other than the standard OS downloadable from raspberrypi.org?

Comment: As this is your second question and it is nearly identical to your first (changing only Julia for golang) and you identify yourself as a beginner, you might advance to intermediate if you applied some focus. Pick a language and learn it well enough to write quality code. You don't need a fancy IDE that will hide the details to do this. And if you get good with a single language you will find picking up another fairly easy.  Further, a web search for a tutorial for whatever language you are interested in plus the word Linux should give you all the information a beginner needs to get started.

Comment: First I did install the official raspbian OS. It used to work pretty well and then I came to know about Pilabs who were the author of twister OS. They claimed their OS to be a bit modified version of the same old raspbian but with a new windows and mac os look. Unfortunately due to some improper installation of a few programs I had to erase the SD card. From then since the sd card was blank I thought to try out the OS.

Comment: Yes it is! (the second one). The purpose for the question was to know if I can use the same IDE as a compiler. As far as I know Julia is a bit like Python and Golang is the successor of C/C++. The former uses Interpreter and the latter, a compiler. I've been using Thonny IDE for Python. Can I use the same for Golang?